# ngTable not loading data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I have two tables in my screen:

(1)

```
<table id="users" class="widget" ng-table="usersTableParams">
                    <tr ng-repeat = "user in $data" ng-click="usersClicked($event, user.userId);">
                        <td >{{user.userId}}</td>
                        <td >{{user.roleName}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

(2)

```
<table class="widget" ng-table="sitesTableParams">
                    <tr ng-repeat = "site in $data">
                        <td >{{site.site}}</td>
                        <td >{{site.country}}</td>
                        <td >{{site.region}}</td>
                        <td >{{site.selected == true ? "Yes" : "No"}}</td>
                        <td >
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{site.selected}}" ng-model="site.selected"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

My script for loading data in two tables:

```
$scope.users =[];
$scope.sitesAssigned =[];   

$scope.selectedUsers = {
            users: []
        };


$scope.usersTableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: startPage,
            count: rowsPerPage,
            sorting: {
                userId: 'asc'
            },
            filter: {
                userId: '',
                roleName:''
            }
        },
        {
            total: $scope.users.length,
            getData: function($defer, params){
                var orderedData = getFilteredSortedData($scope.users, params);
                params.total(orderedData.length);
                var slicedData = getSlicedData(orderedData,params);
                if(null != slicedData && slicedData.length > 0){
                    var user = slicedData[0];
                    if(user.hasOwnProperty('userId')){
                        $scope.selectedUsers.users.push(user.userId);
                        console.log('Selected User: '+JSON.stringify($scope.selectedUsers));
                    }
                }
                $defer.resolve(slicedData);
            }
        });


        $scope.sitesTableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: startPage,
            count: rowsPerPage,
            sorting: {
                site: 'asc'
            },
            filter:{
                site: '',
                country: '',
                region: ''
            }
        },
        {
            total: $scope.sitesAssigned.length,
            getData: function($defer, params){
                var orderedData = getFilteredSortedData($scope.sitesAssigned, params);
                params.total(orderedData.length);
                var slicedData = getSlicedData(orderedData, params);
                $defer.resolve(slicedData);
            }
        }); 
$scope.$watch('sitesTableParams', function(newValue, oldValue){
            console.log('Old value of sitesTableParams: '+JSON.stringify(oldValue));
            console.log('New value of sitesTableParams: '+JSON.stringify(newValue));
        }, true);

            $scope.$watch('selectedUsers', function(newValue, oldValue){
            console.log('Old value of selected users: '+JSON.stringify(oldValue));
            console.log('New value of selected users: '+JSON.stringify(newValue));
            var users = $scope.selectedUsers.users[0];
            console.log('Fetch sites assigned to user: '+users);
            console.log('Sites table params before fetching sites data: '+JSON.stringify($scope.sitesTableParams));
            mlmSiteAssignments.getSites(users).then(function(data){ 
                console.log('List of sites received from service: '+JSON.stringify(data));
                angular.forEach(data, function(site ){
                    $scope.sitesAssigned.push({
                        site: site.site,
                        country: site.country,
                        region: site.region,
                        selected: site.selected
                    });
                });
                $scope.sitesTableParams.data = $scope.sitesAssigned;
                $scope.siteAssignmentsTableParams.reload();
                console.log('Sites table params after fetching sites data: '+JSON.stringify($scope.sitesTableParams));
            });

        }, true);



        var getFilteredSortedData = function(data, params) {
            if (params.filter()) {
                data = $filter('filter')(data, params.filter());
            }
            if (params) {
                data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
            }
            return data;
        };

        var getSlicedData = function(data, params) {
             var slicedData = data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
             return slicedData;
        };
```

On click of a row in 'usersTableParams' the data in 'sitesTableParams' should be loaded. On the click of a row in 'usersTableParams' I am getting the data for second table, but the so obtained data is not getting rendered in the page.

I have been stuck in this issue for several days and unable to find any solution. Any suggestions / corrections / pointers are welcome.

When ran the above code, the console says:

```
Old value of sitesTableParams: {"data":[],"$params":{"page":1,"count":10,"filter":{"site":"","country":"","region":""},"sorting":{"site":"asc"},"group":{},"groupBy":null},"filterBuffer":{}}
New value of sitesTableParams: {"data":[],"$params":{"page":1,"count":10,"filter":{"site":"","country":"","region":""},"sorting":{"site":"asc"},"group":{},"groupBy":null},"filterBuffer":{}}
Old value of selected users: {"users":[]}
New value of selected users: {"users":[]}
Fetch sites assigned to user: undefined
Sites table params before fetching sites data: {"data":[],"$params":{"page":1,"count":10,"filter":{"site":"","country":"","region":""},"sorting":{"site":"asc"},"group":{},"groupBy":null},"filterBuffer":{}}
List of sites received from service: []
Sites table params after fetching sites data: {"data":[],"$params":{"page":1,"count":10,"filter":{"site":"","country":"","region":""},"sorting":{"site":"asc"},"group":{},"groupBy":null},"filterBuffer":{}}
Selected User: {"users":["abc.COM"]}
Old value of selected users: {"users":[]}
New value of selected users: {"users":["abc.COM"]}
Fetch sites assigned to user: abc.COM
Sites table params before fetching sites data: {"data":[],"$params":{"page":1,"count":10,"filter":{"site":"","country":"","region":""},"sorting":{"site":"asc"},"group":{},"groupBy":null},"filterBuffer":{}}
List of sites received from service: [DATA ARRAY]
Sites table params after fetching sites data: {"data":[],"$params":{"page":1,"count":10,"filter":{"site":"","country":"","region":""},"sorting":{"site":"asc"},"group":{},"groupBy":null},"filterBuffer":{}}
```

So the log indicates that even if I got the data in the variable that I am using for populating the data, the watcher for sites table is not called. This implies that the data is not provided to sites table params. Any explanation why this could be happening.

Comment: Can you set your project on plunker or jsFiddle, please?

Comment: I am sorry arman. That will not be possible for me and my apologies for the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

The `getData` function for **ng-table** is called when the controller is loaded. You are making asynchronous calls separately from the 'getData' function, so there is no guarantee the data will have been retrieved by the time the `getData` function is called.

**ng-table** provides a method on the `ngTableParams` object for reloading the data (i.e. it calls `getData` again for you). Example:

```
*ngTableParams*.reload();
```

In `loadUserSites`, you should be calling this method to update the table data like so:

```
mlmSiteAssignments.getSites(users).then(function(data){                 
    angular.forEach(data, function(site){
        $scope.sitesAssigned.push({
            site: site.site,
            country: site.country,
            region: site.region,
            selected: site.selected
        });
    });
    $scope.siteAssignmentsTableParams.reload();
});
```

In turn, this will call `getData`, which will resolve the sorted/paged `$data` for your view.

Comment: I am sorry Taylor, but I gave it a try and your suggestion did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Make sure the call to reload is inside the promise success function. Do you receive any JavaScript errors? Also to confirm, is the users table loading successfully?

Comment: Can you please share the code changes that you are suggesting here. I don't receive any Javascript errors in console. And, yes the users table is loading successfully without any issues.

Comment: Anybody? Any inputs / ideas / suggestions? I am running out of these in my case.

Comment: Whenever, I am trying to reload the table (inside a watcher) after getting the requisite data, I get the error:
TypeError: Cannot set property '$data' of null
I further investigated the issue. This is what I found:
Before, when there is no data for the table, the table params looks like:
{"data":[],"$params":{"page":1,"count":10,"filter":{"location":"","country":"","region":""},"sorting":{"location":"asc"},"group":{},"groupBy":null},"filterBuffer":{}}
After the watch runs, the concerned variable is loaded with data (this is confirmed), but the table params remain unchanged.

Comment: I have updated my code based on the changes I made to my previous comment with console logs. Feel free to ask any questions.